# Directory does not exist on image upload

Tags: opencart

In Opencart v2.3X admin while editing product, I am uploading images on root folder it is giving "direct does not exist" error.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: check the `folder permissions`, maybe the folder is not writable.

Comment: Folder's permission is 777

Comment: Try creating a `sub-folder` in that `root folder` & then try uploading something in that.

Comment: while creating sub-folder it is giving the same error

Comment: Then the `Apache` user does not have write permission on that directory. You need to check that.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem with one of my folders. Realised that my folder name had the symbol "&" on it. That was creating the issue.

Comment: This should be the correct answer (at least for my case)!
was looking everywhere and there was no mentioned about this.. Thanks for saving my day!

Answer (score 0):

if your problem is that at backend,at image manager,you cannot create a new folder,or cannot click a existing folders ,such as "catalog","data" ,

the reason is that you have uploaded a big ,big image ,which is like 2M,to one of these folder.just find the image and delete it ,everything return to normal.

Answer (score 0):

In my case this worked:
check DIR_APPLICATION & DIR_SYSTEM & DIR_IMAGE in config.php

this error occurred in this page:
.../admin/controller/common/filemanager.php
find >> error_directory

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the admin/config.php and config.php path are relatively specified.
E.g

use this

```
define('DIR_APPLICATION', '/Users/yourpcusername/opencart-dev/catalog/');
```

instead of

```
define('DIR_APPLICATION', '../catalog/');
```